# Struct static methods vs class-level methods in Swift

Tags: swift

I like to organize utility methods as static methods in structs in Swift. For example, I might create something like the following

```
struct ImageUtility {
    static func someUtility(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage? { /* ... */ }
    static func otherUtility(_ image: UIImage, croppedTo rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? { /* ... */ }
}
```

It seems that I would be able to do essentially the same thing by using class methods on a class, like so:

```
class ImageUtility {
    class func someUtility(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage? { /* ... */ }
    class func otherUtility(_ image: UIImage, croppedTo rect: CGRect) -> UIImage? { /* ... */ }

}
```

Calling these methods from either the struct or class looks the same, e.g. `let newImage = ImageUtility.someUtility(image)`. Is there any significant difference between these approaches?

Would there be any benefit to putting this all into an extension for an existing class? Like in this case, would it be better to put the `ImageUtility` methods into a `UIImage` extension?

Comment: It's a matter of opinion, but these seem like candidate for `extension` of `UIImage`.

Comment: Making it an extension of `UIImage` is probably the best way to go, but that depends on exactly what it does. If the utility method serves a pretty specific niche purpose, it's best to narrow down it's access specifier. If it's a general feature than make it a public extension

Comment: Yeah, as I was writing this I realized that it seemed like the most logical answer is to put the methods in an extension, but there are also times where I like to have collections of functions namespaced (e.g. `MapUtilities` or `ProfileCache`). In these cases the methods could be put into extensions of related existing classes, but creating a new struct/class to collect them makes it clear that they're related and offers a nice way to organize the methods. If I do this, is there any significant difference (e.g. app load time, compile time) between using `struct` or `class`?